# Error on Mail Send

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

As part of a web design project, I have been testing the following script to send a submitted form as an email using VBScript in Classic ASP. It works with my personal Gmail account when run on my localhost server (IIS 7.5 on Windows 7) provided "Access for less secure apps" is enabled. When I tried to run this code on a remote server (IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012), however, it produced error 80040211 on `Mail.Send`; the fact that this is the same error produced when "Access for less secure apps" is disabled makes me think that Gmail authentication is causing the problem.

```
Set Mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="smtp.gmail.com"
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="******"
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="******"

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Update

Mail.Subject="Form submission"
Mail.From="******"
Mail.To="******"
Mail.TextBody=""

For Each thisItem In Request.QueryString
    Mail.TextBody = Mail.TextBody & thisItem & ": " & Request.QueryString(thisItem) & vbNewLine
Next


Mail.Send
Set testMail=nothing
```

Comment: Does your remote server have its own SMTP server which you could try instead?

Comment: @John I am using a free trial account on this server, which due to spam concerns does not come with an SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what ASP mail components (CDOSYS etc) are configured correctly on the IIS8 server - could be an issue.